# SimpleDateFormat showing incorrect milliseconds with "S" format, but not with "SSS"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm experiencing a problem where a displayed date has the millisecond component multiplied by 10.

Specifically, the time `52.050` is being shown as `52.50` when a `.S` format is used, but `52.050` when a `.SSS` format is used.

Take the following code example:

```java
// Some arbitrary point with 50 milliseconds
final Date date = new Date(1620946852050 l);
final LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

final String format = "%-40s%-20s%-20s%n";
System.out.format(format, "Date Formatter", "Date Format", "Formatted Output");

Stream.of("HH:mm:ss", "HH:mm:ss.S", "HH:mm:ss.SS", "HH:mm:ss.SSS").forEach(dateFormat - > {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.format(format, SimpleDateFormat.class.getName(), dateFormat,
        new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).format(date));
    System.out.format(format, DateTimeFormatter.class.getName(), dateFormat,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat).format(localDateTime));
});
```

This produces an output of:

```
Date Formatter                          Date Format         Formatted Output    

java.text.SimpleDateFormat              HH:mm:ss            00:00:52            
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter      HH:mm:ss            00:00:52            

java.text.SimpleDateFormat              HH:mm:ss.S          00:00:52.50         
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter      HH:mm:ss.S          00:00:52.0          

java.text.SimpleDateFormat              HH:mm:ss.SS         00:00:52.50         
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter      HH:mm:ss.SS         00:00:52.05         

java.text.SimpleDateFormat              HH:mm:ss.SSS        00:00:52.050        
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter      HH:mm:ss.SSS        00:00:52.050
```

I've used both `java.util.Date` and `java.time` to illustrate the unexpected behaviour, and I'm aware that `java.time` is better, but I'd still like to understand the `SimpleDateFormat` behaviour.

I'm running Java 14.0.2.12, but can reproduce in 11.0.10.9.

Comment: It works exactly as described in the [API documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), there's nothing "incorrect" here.

Comment: Specifically the sentence: "Pattern letters are usually repeated, as their number determines the exact presentation; Number: For formatting, **the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits**, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. ".

Comment: If you are using Java 14, maybe consider using class [java.time.DateTimeformatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) rather than class `Simpledateformat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Let's understand how the result produced by `SimpleDateFormat` is confusing (and hence error-prone).

1620946852050 milliseconds = 1620946852000 milliseconds + 50 milliseconds

With 1620946852000, `System.out.println(localDateTime)` will produce the result, `2021-05-14T00:00:52`.

50 milliseconds = (50 / 1000) seconds = 0.05 seconds. This is how `DateTimeFormatter` also presents it. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) describes `S` clearly as: ***fraction-of-second***. In other words, it presents it as a mathematical floating point number of 0.05 up to 9 places of decimal (nanosecond).

You can understand it this way: Pad zeros to the right side of the `String.valueOf(0.05)` to turn the precision up to 9 places of decimal. Thus, it becomes `"0.050000000"`. Now, based on the number of `S`, get the substring of `"0.050000000"`. Note that you can do so only up to 9 places i.e. `SSSSSSSSSS` will throw an exception.

- `S`: .0
- `SS`: .05
- `SSS`: .050
- `SSSS`: .0500 and so on up to
- `SSSSSSSSS`: .050000000

This is the representation we learned in our childhood when we learnt fraction in Mathematics.

On the other hand, `SimpleDateFormat` does not present it as a fraction-of-second; rather, it presents the number after `.` as the number of milliseconds. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) describes `S` as: ***Millisecond***. So, it presents it as a mathematical decimal integer number of 50. This makes it confusing because as soon as we see `.`, we think of fraction whereas `SimpleDateFormat` considers it just a separator for seconds and milliseconds.

The following example illustrates these different ways of presentation:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sdf = 50;
        String dtf = String.format("%.9f", 0.05);

        System.out.format("sdf: %01d, dtf: %s%n", sdf, dtf.substring(0, 3));// Including two places for "0."
        System.out.format("sdf: %02d, dtf: %s%n", sdf, dtf.substring(0, 4));// Including two places for "0."
        System.out.format("sdf: %03d, dtf: %s%n", sdf, dtf.substring(0, 5));// Including two places for "0."
        System.out.format("sdf: %04d, dtf: %s%n", sdf, dtf.substring(0, 6));// Including two places for "0."
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
sdf: 50, dtf: 0.0
sdf: 50, dtf: 0.05
sdf: 050, dtf: 0.050
sdf: 0050, dtf: 0.0500
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.</sup>