# SimpleDateFormat ISO having problems parsing the milliseconds if they have less than 3 digits

Tags: java, date, parsing, iso8601

I'm trying to parse an String into a `java.util.Date`.

Currently, I'm using `SimpleDateFormat`, with the `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"` format String, and it works pretty well most of the time; for example, those work okay:

- `"2022-03-16T12:09:56.267Z"`
- `"2022-03-16T12:11:55.017+03:00"`

The problem lies with perfectly valid ISO strings that happen to use less than three digits for the miliseconds:

- `"2022-03-16T09:18:31.9Z"`

It throws this exception: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2022-03-16T09:18:31.9Z"`.

Is there a way to handle those? Please, do keep in mind that I need to return a `java.util.Date`, but using `SimpleDateFormat` is optional.

I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Please describe "the problem lies [...]". What problem? What do you see when you try to parse that String with the format you have above? It parses fine for me: https://ideone.com/Iam9Pt

Comment: Added the exception to the description.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. I can't repro that.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").parse("2022-03-16T09:18:31.9Z")` works for me using Java 17; it does **not** work with Java 8

Comment: @user16320675 From `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").parse("2022-03-16T09:18:31.9Z").getTime()` I expect 1647422311900 but get 1647422311009 (using Java 11).

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` (when before Java 8 it was reasonable to use it) never supported one or two digits of fraction of second, only three decimals. Related: [SimpleDateFormat showing incorrect milliseconds with "S" format, but not with "SSS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535630/simpledateformat-showing-incorrect-milliseconds-with-s-format-but-not-with-s).

Comment: note: "works for me" on last comment should only be interpreted as "does not throw an Exception" - I have not checked the result nor do I *recommend* the use of `SimpleDateFormat` - it was just a complement to first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71497315/simpledateformat-iso-having-problems-parsing-the-milliseconds-if-they-have-less#comment126370213_71497315) on this question (with link to IDEone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way.

- Note the Z stands for Zulu.
- And also remember that Date does not store any time zone information.
- If necessary, you can modify the ZonedDateTime instance before converting to Date.

```
Instant d = Instant.parse("2022-03-16T09:18:31.9Z");
Date date = Date.from(d);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(date);
```

prints

```
2022-03-16T09:18:31.900Z
Wed Mar 16 05:18:31 EDT 2022
```

I would recommend that you try to convert to using the classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package as they are quite superior to Date.

Comment: If the requirement to return an old-fashioned `Date` is indispensable, then this is the good way. Thanks. Only I’d parse directly into an `Instant` and save the first conversion. Use `Instant.parse("2022-03-16T09:18:31.9Z")`.